# Best practice for font-size inheritance

Tags: css

working on converting our company site over to something more responsive so reworking the `css` to use `em`'s instead of the tried and true `px`.

The problem i'm running into is the inheritance of `font-size` and am looking for best practices for this issue.

This is how I'm solving the problem as of now.

[jsfiddle for your viewing pleasure](http://jsfiddle.net/danferth/uXVNn/)

**HTML**

```
<h3>Heading with a <a href="#">Link</a></h3>

<p>this is a paragraph with a <a href="#">Link</a> inside of it</p>
<a href="#">this is a link outside the paragraph</a>​
```

**CSS**

```css
body {font:normal 100% sans-serif;}
p {font:normal 1.5em sans-serif; margin-bottom:.5em;}
h3 {font:bold 3em serif; margin-bottom:.5em; }
a:link {font-size:1.5em;}

p a, li a, h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a,
h6 a, dl a, blockquote a, dt a, dd a, td a {
    font-size:1em !important;
}
```

I understand that `em`'s are related to the parent `font-size`.  so if I set `p{font-size:1.5em;}` and also set `a:link{font-size:1.5em;}` and my `<a>` is outside of my `<p>` then they will have the same relative size, great.

But if i then place an `<a>` inside a `<p>` the font size of the embedded `<a>` is now larger as it is `1.5em`'s larger than the `<p>`.  To overcome this I set the last style with a string of `p a, li a, h1 a,......{font-size:1em !important;}`. Since `a:link` has a higher specificity than just `p a` i had to use `!important` (not a fan of `!important`), also i can't use `font-size:inherit;` as we have to support, dare i say it, `ie6` (still have 15% traffic, we are biotech and some companies just refuse to upgrade).

So my question to you is this.  Am I going about this the right way in tackling tags inside of tags to prevent my typography from breaking up?  As soon as i wrote the last style i thought to myself, this can become a nightmare to maintain!  I would like to use `rem` but the browser support isn't there for a portion of users.

How do you solve this problem in your own css and what would be a "best practices" approach to this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set font size for blocks only, such as headings and navigation blocks. Changing font inline causes a mess, so just don’t set font size for, say, links. Instead, when desired, set the font size of a `ul` or `div` or other element that contains navigation links.

In general, use as few `font-size` settings as possible, to minimize risks of unwanted cumulative effects.

Notes:

This is not about inheritance at all. When you set `font-size` on an element, the element certainly does not inherit font size. This is about the effect of the relative nature of the `em` unit.

Should you have set `a:link{font-size:1.5em;}` for example, you can easily override it for links inside paragraphs without using `!important`. You just have to be more specific, and the natural way here would be `p a:link{font-size:1em;}`.

Comment: I understand, so my mistake was in setting the font-size for the <a> when it was outside the paragraph tag.  In essence what your saying is I should just wrap the <a> inside of a block that has the font-size set ie a <p>.  This whole em thing is starting to make sese now, Thank you

Comment: What about nested blocks?

Answer (score 4):

You probably should avoid selecting just `a`, and just add a more specific selector for them when you want them to be a different size than what they would inherit from their containers. I never change the font size for just the `a`, and instead change the font sizes on their containers when needed. Similarly, I avoid adding font sizes for other inline elements (e.g. span, em, strong) for the same reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a reset stylesheet such as [Eric Meyer's reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css) which will set the font to inherit on all elements. Then set your default (or "main") font size in `body` and use the relative `em` unit to set the font size on all other elements.

Your issue of "stacking" relative font sizes shouldn't be an issue since you should **rarely** have to set a new font on an element that contains anything other than text, such as the header tags. In the exception situations, the relative font sizes should be intended and an asset to your site, e.g. in a footer area where all text should be a tad smaller than the site default.

In the (rare) cases where relative font sizes causes unwanted behaviour you can always do this:

```
p
{
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

a
{
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

p a
{
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Yup got the reset.css loaded, and set body to 100%. It looks as though you have what i was doing with the `p a{}` selector.  It works and i'm happy with it I guess. I would like to set up a typography.css if you will and then just forget about it until like you say the exception comes around.  I guess I just want to know if this is how everyone is tackling the issue of font inheritance. Or am i missing something grand that solves the problem. Other than `rem`.

Comment: This is how I do it, and I've never bumped into an exception moment. It's just so rare to have to specify a new font on an element that has children, and even rarer that the stacking font size is not intended. I'd say it's nothing to worry about

Comment: Good to know, I like the idea of responsive design and when I ran into this issue i set the `p a{}` style and thought, maybe there's a better way.  Thanks for letting me know I headed in the right direction.