# If you apply CSS font-size to the body element how do you handle nesting tags and inheritance?

Tags: html, css

I am redesigning a site with a lot of old content.  The primary design change is making the site elastic to fill various screen sizes.  I am using the font-size in the body element as the mechanism to do this and setting any measurements to ems.  This works as expected but I am having trouble when I find a nested element that also has font-size specified.  In the example below I show how inserting a span tag inside of a p tag that has a class with  font-size assigned to it causes the font-size to be inherited and essentially applied twice.  I know this is how it works but how do I deal with it?  I run into this a lot with links and lists and styles for bolding text.

The reason the body gets set to 1em is so that I can detect screen resolution and change the value of the font-size to make the entire design shrink or grow proportionally.  All of the design elements have been converted from px to em.

Nice example here: http://v1.jontangerine.com/log/2007/09/the-incredible-em-and-elastic-layouts-with-css

I think the only way around it is to edit the existing posts and updating the styles used to new ones this into consideration.  There are hundreds of posts....really hoping there may be something I am missing.

This is a basic example.  Any suggestions?

```
    <style type="text/css">
    html {
        font-size:100%;
    }
    body {
        font-size:1em;
    }
    .smalltext, ul, a {
        font-family: "Century Gothic", Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: .75em;
    }
    .boldNavy {
        font-family: "Century Gothic", Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: .75em;
        font-weight:bold;
        color:navy;
    }
    </style>

    <div>
      <p class="boldNavy">Here is the bold text as it should appear</p>
      <p><a href="#">A Link as it should appear</a></p>
      <p class="smalltext">Text as it should appear, now look at what happens when you put tags inside each other.</p>
      <p class="smalltext"><span class="boldNavy">The bold text is smaller here since it is inheriting font-size from the p tag.</span> this is my regular text <a href="#">and a link</a>.  The paragraph goes on and on...</p>
      <ul>
        <li><span class="boldNavy">Bullet List 1</span><br />
          This is the description and <a href="#">a link</a></li>
        <li><span class="boldNavy">Bullet List 2</span><br />
          This is the description and <a href="#">a link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is your goal? What is the desired design? If you know what you want, you can find a way to achieve that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307317/best-practice-for-font-size-inheritance

Comment: found that one too Danko, thanks for posting it.  I realize what causes the problem and how to keep it from happening on a fresh design.  The challenge is all of the baggage the new design is carrying over from previous design.

The reason for setting font-size to 1em in the body is so that when I detect screen resolution I can change it to make the entire site grow or shrink and all of the design elements stay proportional.  Anything that has a size attribute gets set in ems and scales nicely.  Like I said the problem is with previous content that had been styled without this consideration.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how much of IE you want to support (IE9 +), I'd suggest using `rem` which stands for root `em`. This will eliminate the cascade affect you get with `em` values. Check out this article: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem

Comment: It is not clear at all which problem `rem` would solve in the context. It would certainly *create* a problem with older versions of IE.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't clarify enough. By defining the font size in `rem` units instead of `em`, the font size of nested elements will not be compounded. If user3250268 is using other CSS3 properties then he's not supporting below IE9 (for the most part) anyways. You can always set a fallback.

Comment: Unfortunately it is an intranet and they use IE exclusively.

Comment: Personally, and I'm sure some would disagree, if you are forced to support older versions of IE (I'm in the same boat with my Agency's intranet) then I'd just stick with using `px` for font sizes.

Comment: the elastic design was at the CEO's (ahem) request.  I think I can create style rules for nested elements and bump the font-size up but it is kind of an ugly solution but easier than going through hundreds of posts and updating to new styles that might have some of the same problems.  I will post my results.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Setting e.g. `font-size: .75em` does not cause inheritance. Quite the opposite: it *prevents* inheritance. But it sets the font size to 3/4 of the font size of the parent element. This seldom makes sense (it normally makes the font too small if the parent element font size was normal copy text size), but most importantly, just don’t set font size that way if you don’t mean it.

There is no magic cure to font size settings (though there is a lot of snake oil being merchandised). For example, if you wish to reduce font size for a list of links—you shouldn’t, but let’s assume you do—then set `font-size` on the `ul` containing the list, and leave it that. It would be pointless (even absurd) to *also* set reduced font size on `a` elements inside such a list, for example.

Comment: But it sets the font size to 3/4 of the font size of the parent element...isn't this inheritance?

Comment: No, it is not inheritance; inheritance, when it takes place, sets a property to the same value as the parent element’s value for that property.